# Do inclusions in the closed unit balls under different norms imply ordering of the norms?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Given two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|\cdot\|'$ and $\|\cdot\|$, it is clear that if $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|' \leq \|\boldsymbol{x}\|$ for all $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the following inclusion holds for the closed unit balls:
$$
    B_1^{\|\cdot\|} \subseteq B_1^{\|\cdot\|'}.
$$

Is the reverse implication true ($B_1^{\|\cdot\|} \subseteq B_1^{\|\cdot\|'} \implies \|\boldsymbol{x}\|' \leq \|\boldsymbol{x}\| \quad \forall \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$), and how would one go about proving it?

Comment: $x \neq 0$ implies $\frac x {\|x\|} \in B_1^{\|.\|}$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [geetha290krm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064504/geetha290krm) for the hint, I am writing up the proof here for completeness.

$$
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{x} \neq 0 &\implies \frac{\boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|} \in B_1^{\|\cdot\|} \\
    &\implies \frac{\boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|} \in B_1^{\|\cdot\|'} \\
    &\implies \left\|\frac{\boldsymbol{x}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|}\right\|' \leq 1 \\
    &\implies \frac{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|'}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|} \leq 1 \\
    &\implies \|\boldsymbol{x}\|' \leq \|\boldsymbol{x}\| \\
\end{align*}
$$

and the $\boldsymbol{x} = 0$ case follows trivially from the properties of the norm.